# Error compiling gstreamer app in petalinux

Tags: gstreamer, petalinux

I'm trying to compile a custom gstreamer app in petalinux  with the next header files:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
```

The petalinux project already has the sysroot library sources populated after run:

```
petalinux-build --sdk
petalinux-package --sysroot
```

But compiling the app (petalinux-build -c myapp) I've got the next error:

```
| myapp.c:25:10: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
|  #include <gst/gst.h>
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
```

The make file is:

```
APP = myapp

# Add any other object files to this list below
APP_OBJS = myapp.o

all: build

build: $(APP)

$(APP): $(APP_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APP_OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    -rm -f $(APP) *.elf *.gdb *.o

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 glib-2.0)
```

And the recipe:

```
#
# This file is the myapp recipe.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple myapp application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://myapp .c \
       file://Makefile \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
         oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 myapp ${D}${bindir}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing and how to add correctly the gstreamer paths for compilation?

**EDIT**

As suggested I added the DEPENDS line in the recipe:

```
#
# This file is the myapp recipe.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple myapp application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://myapp .c \
       file://Makefile \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 gstreamer1.0"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good"

do_compile() {
         oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 myapp ${D}${bindir}
```

But unfortunately still giving same error...any ideas what could be wrong/missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it will help you that much, but there is a template provided by GStreamer to start building your application. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template
Note that autotools is probably dropped in favor of Meson.

Comment: Thanks vermaete, I already have the application and it is working I'd only need to compile and add it to the petalinux project.

Comment: Well, the solution of the problem could lay in the makefile and not in the bb recipe.  Anyhow, I thought GStreamer left autotools and moved to Meson.  Most of the yocto recipes will be build and maintained for Meson.

Comment: Yes it could be down to the makefile, but how could I add the paths to be able to compile the basic gstreamer app? I even tried to compile directly in the recipe adding the line (instead oe_runmake): ${CC} ${WORKDIR}/http-launch.c -o http-launch ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer1.0 and still same error, I'm really lost with this, any clue/help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, what I've done is instead to use the makefile to compile , is to use the recipe and more importantly to add `inherit pkgconfig` line,  in order to force to populate sysroot during compilation, this is the final working recipe, hope it can help to someone else with same issue:

```
    #
    # This file is the myapp recipe.
    #

    SUMMARY = "Simple myapp application"
    SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
    LICENSE = "MIT"
    LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

    SRC_URI = "file://myapp .c \
           file://Makefile \
              "

    S = "${WORKDIR}"

    DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 gstreamer1.0"
    RDEPENDS_${PN} = "gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good"

    inherit pkgconfig 

    do_compile() {
             ${CC} ${WORKDIR}/myapp.c -o myapp ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` 
    }

    do_install() {
             install -d ${D}${bindir}
             install -m 0755 myapp ${D}${bindir}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the DEPENDS pointing to the GStreamer packages needed to get you code compiled.  Having them at the image is not enough to have this recipe build.

You could take a look at the recipe to build the RTSP server of GStreamer (http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server_1.16.1.bb?h=master)

> DEPENDS = "gstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base"

Comment: thanks for your answer, I added the DEPENDS line, but unfortunately still not working, I edit my question with the new recipe.